# Unable to load ui.bootstrap module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem loading ui.bootstrap module in angular - I get the following error message and angular won't start:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module mailingexchangeApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

This is how I load the module:

```
var exampleApp = angular.module('exampleApp', ['ui.bootstrap']).config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');
});
```

And this is what libraries I include, all in head section:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.2.min"></script>
<script src="/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="/js/tablesorter/tables.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

What's wrong? How can I solve this?

Comment: `<script src="/js/controllers.js"></script>` must be the last javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading the actual js file, in your html, after you are attempting to access it:

```
<script src="/js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.2.min"></script>
```

Any code you want to reference in controller.js, needs to be loaded before controllers.js.
So the easiest fix is to swap their position in your HTML. But it's likely that the other files will also need to be loaded first.